# How to make modal appear above all divs

Tags: html, css

I have this flex slider to show a customers previous purchases/orders, it uses a "slider" div and inside that is a `foreach` statement to pull the users previous purchases from a database to produce each "slide" within the slider.

In each slide there is a button to open the modal, which works fine if there is only one item there, but if there is 2-3 items then the `display:flex` is activated - causing the modal to pop up inside the slider div rather than on top of everything, I believe it has something to do with the `position:relative` for the "slider" CSS and the `position` for the modal CSS

and I cant move the modal outside of those divs because the modal needs to be inside the `foreach` statement so that it pops up with the correct item details (since they are being pulled from a database).

Also, I cant seem to replicate the issue on my PC when I narrow my browser as much as I can (guessing the window doesn't go narrow enough for the issue to occur).

Had this issue a long time, any help is appreciated, thanks

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* Firefox */
}

.slider::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.slide {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 140px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider>div {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.slider img {
  margin: 6px 6px;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  z-index: 1200 !important;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.45);
}

.modal-backdrop {
  display: none !important;
}

.modal-content {
  color: black !important;
  z-index: 1200 !important;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: .3rem;
  outline: 0;
}

i.fa-ellipsis-v {
  border-radius: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #888;
  padding: 0.5em 0.6em;
  font-size: 14px;
}

i.fa-ellipsis-v:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" id="bootstrap-css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide" id="slide-1">
    <img src="/images/products/<?php echo $ditt['prodimage'];?>">

    <i data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal-1"></i>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top:64px;">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Order options</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="/images/products/<?php echo $ditt['prodimage']; ?>">
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-2">
    <img src="/images/products/<?php echo $ditt['prodimage'];?>">

    <i data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal-2"></i>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal-2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top:64px;">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Order options</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="/images/products/<?php echo $ditt['prodimage']; ?>">
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-3">
    <img src="/images/products/<?php echo $ditt['prodimage'];?>">
    <i data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal-3"></i>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal-3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top:64px;">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Order options</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="/images/products/<?php echo $ditt['prodimage']; ?>">
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] with the rendered HTML and CSS, the PHP is irrelevant here

Comment: @j08691 like I said in my question, I am fetching the previous orders from a database and I'm just trying to show where the foreach statement is and how the slider works etc.

Comment: That's fine, but for us to reproduce the issue, we need a [mcve] and your PHP won't help us, we need the rendered HTML/CSS/JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

If you’re wanting the modal above all other elements in the window you can use position:fixed and z-index:99999

```
.modal{
    position:fixed;top:calc(50% - 200px);left:calc(50% - 250px);width:500px;height:400px:z-index:99999;
}
```

Comment: modal still appears inside slider

Answer (score 0):

First of all set these attributes

```
.Modal{
  position:absolute

}
.slider{
position:relative
top:0; //as default to overwrite browser defaults for non-static elements
left:0;//as default to overwrite browser defaults for non-static elements
}
```

Now Your .Modal will be visible in constraints of .slider.
Anyway if Your .Modal be visible out of the .slider

- edit .slider{overflow} value

or

- YOu can set .modal{position:fixed } or YOu can put YOur .modal out of .slider :
  `<div class="Modal></div><div class="slider>...</div>`

Prevent from using z-index - it's unintuitive.
Z-index is worth just for dynamic purpose, like programaticly switching visible images layed out in the same constraints.

By the way
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/f9q3021e/) You can figure out Your snippet to be reproducable.

Comment: I already tried that CSS, the modal still appears inside the slider on mobile devices, also when I move the modal outside of the slider div it doesnt show at all, also I have a `foreach` statement inside the slider div so each slide div is a row from database, and the modal needs to be inside the `foreach` statement for that

Comment: Then You just run Your code and copy/paste here or in jsfiddle.net. both : desktop and mobile version (switch in DevTools between desktop/mobile).
I doubt You tried fixed as it is positioned relative to the viewport .
You should read about position attibute [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp)
If my example with relative, absolute didnt work, maybe some higher ancestor cuts it out.

Answer (score 0):

### Just a modal using the bootstrap classes:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" id="bootstrap-css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Bootstrap carousel with modal

```css
.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main-container {
  border: solid yellow 2px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#carouselExampleControls {
  border: solid green 1px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #88dd8811;
}

.modal-container {
  display: block;
  height: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="other-container">Other container</div>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-indicators bg-success">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="modal-container d-flex flex-row p-3 justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="me-2">Happy people modal here:</div>
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-25 me-1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#firstModal">
  Launch FIrst modal
</button>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade modal-centered" id="firstModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="firstModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="firstModalLabel">Big Dog title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <span class="ms-5 p-3 text-white bg-warning">I am a big dog!</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of first modal -->
            <div class="modal-container">
              <!-- Button trigger modal -->
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModalTwo">
  Launch demo modal two
</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalTwo" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalTwoLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalTwoLabel">Modal two title</h5>
                      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <span> I am a fish!</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="modal-container m-3">I will hold a modal</div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="modal-container m-3">I will hold a modal</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev text-primary" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-primary" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next text-success" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon  bg-primary" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Original example:

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* Firefox */
}

.slider::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.slide {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 140px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider>div {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.slider img {
  margin: 6px 6px;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  z-index: 1200 !important;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.45);
}

.modal-backdrop {
  display: none !important;
}

.modal-content {
  color: black !important;
  z-index: 1200 !important;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: .3rem;
  outline: 0;
}

i.fa-ellipsis-v {
  border-radius: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #888;
  padding: 0.5em 0.6em;
  font-size: 14px;
}

i.fa-ellipsis-v:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" id="bootstrap-css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

Slider does not run and style seems to have no effect on it
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide" id="slide-1">
    <img src="/images/products/<?php echo $ditt['prodimage'];?>"  alt="prodimage1">
    <i class="bi-bag-fill" style="font-size: 3rem; color: orange;" data-toggle="modal"  data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal-1"></i>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top:64px;">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Order options</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="/images/products/<?php echo $ditt['prodimage']; ?>" alt="prodimage1">
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-2">
    <img src="/images/products/<?php echo $ditt['prodimage'];?>" alt="prodimage2">
    <i class="bi-bag-fill" style="font-size: 3rem; color: orange;" data-bs-toggle="modal"  data-bs-target="#exampleModal-2"></i>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal-2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top:64px;">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Order options</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="/images/products/<?php echo $ditt['prodimage']; ?>" alt="prodimage2">
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-3"  data-bs-target="#exampleModal-3">
    <img src="/images/products/<?php echo $ditt['prodimage'];?>" alt="prodimage3">
    <i class="bi-bag-fill" style="font-size: 3rem; color: orange;"data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal-3"></i>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal-3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top:64px;">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Order options</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="/images/products/<?php echo $ditt['prodimage']; ?>"  alt="prodimage3">
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```